# Why the option to use attributes in new ATL projects was removed from Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, atl

This is the text from MSDN comment: "According to the book ATL Internals (2ed) the use of attributes is deprecated and should not be used in new ATL projects."

But WHY?!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ATL these attributes were a compiler trick. They were not a core part of the platform like attributes in C#. They were also more confusing to debug than macros's and the method of dumping generated attribute code was a hassle.

I suspect another issue is likely to have been C++ compiler compatibility and standards-adherence. Attributes didn't make for more beautiful C++ code, and perhaps this syntax may be used in a future version of a real C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Appendix D of the book goes into this.

Attributed ATL requires compiler extensions, and the problems encountered include

- debugging either code generated by the attribute or the interaction between the attribute and your code
- no control over the code generated
- bugs, especially around connection points