# How do you load data into an attributed database class generated by the MFC application wizard?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012, atl, visual-c++-2012

Using the MFCApplication wizard in Visual C++ 2012, if "Generate attributed database class" is checked, a header with some special syntax (attributed C++ classes) are generated, which look like this:

```
// MFCApplication2Set.h: interface of the CMFCApplication2Set class
//

#pragma once

// code generated on March-05-13, 9:26 AM

[
    db_source(L"Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;..."),
    db_table(L"dbo.tblEmployee")
]
class CMFCApplication2Set
{
public:
... big list of stuff that corresponds to the fields in your db table omitted ...
}
```

The above header corresponds to a mostly empty implementation file:

```
// MFCApplication2Set.cpp : implementation of the CMFCApplication2Set class
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication2.h"
#include "MFCApplication2Set.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CMFCApplication2Set implementation
```

That was the WHOLE implementation class. Notice that:

A.  No parent class name is specified anywhere.
 B.  There's some "Visual C++ magic" going on here, that is, as a novice to modern C++, I'm lost.
      `db_source` is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws9w5a0e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but the documentation is pretty thin or at least opaque to me.

Questions:

1. I was mystified by this syntax when I first saw it, but I figured out it's probably a variant of this [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh877381.aspx) feature in Visual C++. It is that, right?
2. How am I meant to I use these generated "attributed database class" objects?  I found [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda1743k.aspx) but if you look carefully at that documentation, that code sample is showing people the Old Way and the New Way, and is not telling me what I want to know which is how to use this new object that the IDE can not give me any documentation or code completion features for. Also since the generated code for the `CMFCApplication2Set` class generated by the wizard does not reference any types or class names, I'm lost. If I could even use some IDE feature to know what methods and stuff have been Magically Injected into this Magical mystery Object, I'd be better off.  The only think I can think to do is to learn the old way and learn all the things you can call from the old two-separate-ATL-types world, and then somehow learn to combine them.

In a nutshell, I'm looking for the minimum syntax I need to know to actually use one of these Attributed Database Class instances, variables, as they are generated in a new MFC app by the wizard.  The instance shown below is a member of an MFC document class and `CMFCApplication2Set m_MFCApplication2Set` is declared as a field inside the MFC document class.

What I have tried is to use this "untyped object".  This object appears to have lots of data fields (m_X) and has only one method that shows up in IDE code completion, called `GetRowSetProperties`.  Thanks to whatever magic or injection is going on, this generated Attributed Database Class (which does not visibly inherit anything) is a complete mystery to me at edit time and compile time.

Here's me just trying to inspect this thing to see if it even initialized itself when its constructor ran:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication2Doc::OnNewDocument() {     if (!CDocument::OnNewDocument())        return FALSE;

        TRACE( m_MFCApplication2Set.m_AStringFieldName); // outputs NOISE.



    return TRUE; }
```

At compile time and edit time, the IDE gives me NO help about the types involved in this "anonymous" class that inherits from nothing, but which gets lots of secret powers due to some kind of Injection via those attributes I'm guessing. At debug time, I can see that there is more than just a bunch of data fields in this C++ class, but this still doesn't help me know how to use it. A minimal code sample of using one of these to go get a recordset from the database, would be great.

[image]

Update: Calling `OpenDataSource` is fun, because it compiles but the IDE doesn't think it should be valid.  Nevertheless, it runs, and returns 0 as the result, but that doesn't actually initialize this [CThingyThatVisualStudioGaveYouThatYouDontKnowWhatItIs](http://www.ifwiki.org/index.php/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deprecated feature of attributed C++ code. Pre-processor expands code and replaces attributes with actual base classes. If you enable generation of these intermediate files, things are going to be more clear to you:

[image]

You will have `XXX.mrg.cpp` and `XXX.mrg.h` files generated, which you can review and see the *real* C++ code forwarded to compiler.

The attributes will be replaced with substituted bases classes, maps like [`BEGIN_COLUMN_MAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8ef5853%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) etc. The attributed source code is compact, but the feature is deprecated and looking into expanded code it should be easy (if necessary) to strip the attributes and copy expanded code right into source. It's easy with DB attributes, and more difficult with COM attributes since the internal dependencies are most sophisticated.

Comment: I can't find any reference in the doc to it being deprecated.

Comment: MSDN does not mark them as deprecated , but there is nothing to support the opposite reasoning. It was experimental feature in Visual studio 2003, 2005, then removed as an option for new ATL projects, not developed since then either. Some say ATL Internals book [does not recommend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310/why-the-option-to-use-attributes-in-new-atl-projects-was-removed-from-visual-stu) them for new projects.

Comment: Weird that the MFC Application wizard still generates this ugly syntax.